# Would "my learned things" be correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I would like to know if saying "my learned things" could be correct or not.

For example :

> I want to save my learned things in a file

I searched the exact words "my learned things" in Google, **and only got 27 results**, so I'm very unsure.

If it is not correct, could you advise me with any other correct form to say "the things I learned".

Thanks you !

Comment: Hmm?  What's wrong with "the things I learned"?  I'd post that as an answer, but you appear to already know the phrase.  In any case, no, "my learned things" definitely sounds unusual.

Comment: @snailboat In fact, it's for a web domain name, and thingsilearned is already taken (not a surprise though), thats why I'm looking for another way to say "the things I learned".
If "my learned things" sounds unusual, I guess it's a bad idea for a web domain name. :/  Thanks anyway

Comment: Alternatives could be *whatilearned* or *whativelearned*

Comment: @StoneyB Sounds good, yes. I was too focused on the "things" word. Thanks you.

Comment: can someone explain a rule here? i am putting various verbs in this sentence and some are fine and some aren't. e.g. "chosen, preferred, selected" are fine but "learned, gained" are not.

Comment: That last comment is a very interesting question, which I myself would like to see an answer to. I suggest you post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *my learned things* does sound rather uncommon and unusual. *Things that I learnt* would be a better replacement.

Comment: In American English, we accept *learnt* but most of us would say *learned* instead.

Comment: yes. I did think so. So in that case, either should be fine. You can also use *Things that I learned*, *learnt* would be accurate too...

Comment: Oh, certainly.  I didn't mean to imply that *learnt* was wrong--I just wanted to add an American perspective.

Comment: Yes. Right you are.